# How can ı get last price and convert coin curreny to usdt

Tags: python, tkinter, binance

I want the code to get the last price and use it to divide the entered quantity (qty = "entered quantity" / "last price"). Finally, use the quantity to open a short or long order.I have a search bar and an input field for quantity. From the search bar, I can select all the USDT pairs available in Binance Futures. Currently #deneme field gets last price too but it's not working in the end.

```
from tkinter import *
from operator import truediv
import os
import tkinter
from pickle import TRUE
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from binance.client import Client

####API KEYS
api_key = os.environ.get('binance_api')
api_secret = os.environ.get('binance_secret')
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)



#Ekran
root= Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')

l = Label(root, text="MARKET ORDER")
l.config(font=("MARKET ORDER", 25))
l.pack()

#Bar
l = Label(root, text="Coin Girin")
l.config(font=("Coin Girin", 10))
l.pack()
lst = exchange_info = client.futures_exchange_info()
usdt_pairs = [s['symbol'] for s in exchange_info['symbols'] if 'USDT' in s['symbol']]
print(usdt_pairs)

def search(event):
    value = event.widget.get()

    if value == '':
        combo_box['values'] = usdt_pairs
    else:
            data = []
            for item in usdt_pairs:
                if value.lower() in item.lower():
                    data.append(item)
            combo_box['values'] = data



combo_box = ttk.Combobox(root,value=usdt_pairs)
combo_box.set('')
combo_box.pack()

combo_box.bind('<KeyRelease>', search)


#deneme
def show_ticker_info(event=None):
    selected_symbol = combo_box.get()
    ticker_info = client.futures_ticker(symbol=selected_symbol,timeframe='1m')
    ticker_text.config(text=ticker_info['lastPrice'])
    root.after(100, show_ticker_info) # update price every 100 milliseconds

ticker_text = Label(root, text="")
ticker_text.pack()
combo_box.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", show_ticker_info)
root.after(0, show_ticker_info) # start updating immediately

#qty girme
l = Label(root, text="Miktar Girin")
l.config(font=("Miktar Girin", 10))
l.pack()
qty_entry = Entry(root)
qty_entry.pack()


#Buton SAT
def buttonFunction():
    qty = qty_entry.get()
    selected_symbol = combo_box.get()
    order = client.futures_create_order(symbol=selected_symbol,
                                        side=Client.SIDE_SELL,
                                        type=Client.ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
                                        leverage=20,
                                        quantity=qty)
    if order:

        global pop
        pop = Toplevel(root)
        pop.title("SELL")
        pop.geometry("250x150")
        pop.config(bg="green")
        pop_label = Label(pop, text="ORDER PLACED", bg="black", fg="white")
        pop_label.pack(pady=10)

b = Button(root, text="SAT", bg="red", fg="white", command=buttonFunction)
b.config(font=("bas", 18))
b.pack(side=LEFT)
#Buton AL
def buttonFunction2():
    selected_symbol = combo_box.get()
    qty = qty_entry.get()
    order = client.futures_create_order(symbol=selected_symbol,
                                        side=Client.SIDE_BUY,
                                        type=Client.ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
                                        leverage=20,
                                        quantity=qty)
    if order:

        global pop
        pop = Toplevel(root)
        pop.title("BUY")
        pop.geometry("250x150")
        pop.config(bg="green")
        pop_label = Label(pop, text="ORDER PLACED", bg="black", fg="white")
        pop_label.pack(pady=10)

b2 = Button(root, text="AL", bg="green", fg="white", command=buttonFunction2,)
b2.config(font=("bas", 18))
b2.pack(side=RIGHT)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you don't need to bind `<<ComboboxSelected>>` to `show_ticker_info()` because you have already started a *after loop* on that function.  With the binding, a new *after loop* will be created whenever you change the selection of the combobox.  Also if you can get the *last price*, then what is your problem actually?

Comment: ıdk how can ı get usdt qty before buy or sell order.

Comment: Does `qty = qty_entry.get()` already do what you want? I wonder why you don't know.

Comment: For example with my code ı can only buy btcusdt with btc amount like, buy 0.006 btc. I want to change that to usdt buy $7 worth of btc.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot test your code. You can modify my example.

Snippet:

```
import locale

amount = 125000

# set locale to US
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
# format US currency value
US_dollar = locale.currency(amount, grouping=True)
print(US_dollar)
```

Result: $125,000.00